# Paypal processing error in Prestashop

Tags: paypal, prestashop

Current Prestashop version `1.6.0.6` .

Latest Paypal Modul installed `3.7.2` .

Paypal Modul is installed correctly.

Error-Description: I can not upload a screenshot due to lack of reputation. You can see it by clicking [this link](http://rfsoftlab.com/paypal-error.jpg)

When I want to order via Paypal I do get the error message:

> ```
> Error occurred:
> Please try to contact the merchant:
> PayPal response:
> ->
> ```

Please suggest a way to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to upload to the latest version of paypal (3.8.1) in modules. 3.7.2 is no longer working.